# relationship between standard errors of the inputs and the covariances

Tags: multiple-regression, covariance, standard-error

I've got a multi linear regression too big for excel's linest, as there are 230,000 rows of values.  So building linest equivalent by hand using COVARs. The COVAR approach is nice because it avoids a matrix multiplication with [4 x 230,000] x [230,000 x 4] multiplication.  The matrix is composed of COVAR results, and matrix math done on the simple matrix of covars.

I can reproduce most of linest using COVAR's, except the SE_x.  I can show that the (SE_x)² is proportional to the covar(residual vs residual)/covar(x vs x).  But what is that "constant" fraction that relates COVAR(resid,resid)/COVAR(x,x) to (SE_x)²? By "constant", I mean the ratio is the same for all x, not literally a constant.

I tried an experiment altering a value of y. The constant does not depend on the y or estimate values.  I tried an experiment altering a single x value.  The constant changed value for all inputs, but was still consistent across all inputs.  The only parameter that I can think of that would affect all inputs equally is the determinant of the COVARs matrix.

So I'm expecting that the proportional relationship between (SE_x)² and COVAR(resid,resid)/COVAR(x,x) is a function of the the COVAR matrix determinant, DOF, and n.

What is the function of that proportion?

Comment: You could easily do this in R.

Comment: Yes. R. Weka. Lots of other packages.  Do you know the relationship between SE_x² and the other parameters?

Comment: can you make some of your notation more explicit? What is $SE_x$, for instance? Is this the standard deviation of a particular column of your $X$ matrix? And when you write 'COVAR(resid,resid)/COVAR(x,x)', what exactly is 'resid' and 'x'?

Comment: Just a guess, but if your $SE_x^2$ is the estimate $\hat \sigma^2$ of the error variance $\sigma^2$ then $\hat \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{n-p - 1} \sum_i (y_i - \hat y_i)^2 = \frac{n-1}{n-p - 1} \hat V(e)$, where $n$ is the number of observations, $p$ is the number of predictors without intercept, and $\hat V(e)$ is the sample variance of the residual vector $e$. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: So I'm building excel LINEST by hand.  LINEST has an SE_x for each independent input's beta in the second row the LINEST output.  resid is the residuals marked as e in your comment above.  The SE_x is proportional to the SE_x/SE_y for all x.  But how does one calculation the proportion?